# Is GA code needed when I use Google Tag Manager

Tags: tags, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics

I am trying to use Google Tag Manager and implement a custom dimension in a website. I use code igniter and need to get how many facebook, twitter and googleplus logins there are. I already inserted the dataLayer in the body above the GTM code but it seems the dataLayer.push isn't sending anything to GA. I am not seeing any pageviews or custom dimensions fired in GA. Is there anything else I need to do?

```
<body>
 <script>
  dataLayer = [];
 </script>

<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<noscript><iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-XXXXXX"
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXXXX');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->

 <script>
  dataLayer.push({'socialType': '<?php echo $adapter->id; ?>'});
 </script>
```

Do I need to put the regular GA code or does GTM insert this for me?

Answer (score 0):

From what you already have you also need to do the following:

1. Make sure that you have created a tag for Google Analytics in your tag manager account for page views, I assume that you have already done this.
2. Make sure that you have created another tag for Google Analytics, set the Analytics ID and then set the type of tag to **Social**.